# match a column of strings against columns in other tables

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, psql, tsvector

In Postgres, how can you match a string against columns in other tables? For each row in Table I `string` column, search all rows in Table II and Table III for matches and return them `/` concatenated.

My goal is to derive match words and match structures from a string input.

**Table I:** Strings

```
string             | match_words | match_structures
---------------------------------------------------
Hi, my name is dan |             |
```

**Table II:** Words

```
word
----------
hello
hi
bird
name
```

**Table III:** Structures

```
structure
----------
hi, my name is
hello, my
how are you?
my is
```

**Desired Output:** Table I: Strings

```
string             | match_words | match_structures
---------------------------------------------------
Hi, my name is dan | hi/name     | hi, my name is/my is
```

---

**Attempts:**

Using iLike: I get the first match `hi`, but not all substring matches:

```
update dialog set match_words = word from words where string ilike '%' || word || '%';
```

Giving me

```
string             | match_words | match_structures
---------------------------------------------------
Hi, my name is dan | hi          |
```

---

Doing a select, I can pair the full string to the individual words, which I guess is the opposite of what I want:

```
select string, word, structure from dialog left join words on (string ilike '%' || word || '%') left join structures on (string ilike '%' || structure || '%');

       string       | word |   structure    
--------------------+------+----------------
 Hi, my name is dan | hi   | hi, my name is
 Hi, my name is dan | name | hi, my name is
```

This is still missing the structure `my ____ is`

Answer (score 0):

first you have to use a substring
you need to take table 1 and divide each value of the string row
 in a string array
the second is to do the same with table 2
the third is to compare your tables
you will need to use as two loops to verify each position of array 1 with array 2

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html
https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/substring-function.php